# Transferring FSMO roles over vpn

Tags: windows, domain-controller

I have a server located at one of our offices which is quite old and is due to be upgraded soon, this server holds the FSMO roles, I have another server in another office, both are DC's in the same domain and both are replicated, both run Server 2003 standard. I need to transfer the FSMO roles from the old server to the the one I have in the other office before I upgrade. Also I am looking at bringing in Exchange 2010 server however I cant install/configure that until I transfer the roles as it needs to be at the same site as the schema master. My question really is as both servers replicate over a vpn, how quickly will the roles transfer and will there be downtime as I need to make sure that while the transfer is running, both servers will service logon's and share files. or would it be better to do it out of hours?
many thanks and apologies if I've missed out anything
Regards
Tom

Answer (score 3):

They should transfer within a second or two at the most.

Comment: even over a slow VPN?

Comment: Pretty much. FSMO roles dont come with hugh data that gets transferred. It is MOSTLY just an AD entry where they reside.

Comment: many thanks, I plan to do this today at some point so I'll post the results for anyone else who needs the info.

Comment: just to let you all know that the transfer took approx 5 mns to take all the FSMO roles across. this is probably caused by contacted the existing operations master for each role. Many many thanks for your advice